# How access another fragment from a fragment in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

```
  val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context)
    dialog.setTitle("Confirmation")
    dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?")
    dialog.setPositiveButton("YES"){ text, listener ->
        sharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply()
        println("Shared preferences cleared")
        println("Logged out")
        val intent =  Intent(activity as Context, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    dialog.setNegativeButton("NO"){text,listener ->
        
        val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        val beginTransaction = activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        beginTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, homeFragment)
        beginTransaction.commit()
        activity!!.navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.home_screen)
        println("Home title set")
        activity!!.actionBar!!.title = "Home"
        
    }
    dialog.create()
    dialog.show()
```

I want to go the Home Fragment when the user clicks the "No" Button. I am being directed to the Home Fragment but the dialog box does not disappear and when I click no again, the app crashes giving a Null Pointer Exception on the line :

```
val beginTransaction = activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
```

How can I remove the dialog box when I reach the home fragment?
Please help.

Comment: The first thing I want to tell you is that the force unwrapping of the activity `activity!!.supportFragmentManager` is very dangerous. Be careful with these force unwraps.

Comment: yes, but the compiler gives an error if I don't use !! operator

Comment: That is because you should use it like this, probably;


`val beginTransaction = activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
beginTransaction?.let{
                it.replace(R.id.frameLayout, homeFragment)
                it.commit()
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Call `dialog.dismiss();` before committing the transaction
And also before moving to another activity

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context)
.setTitle("Confirmation")
.setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?") 
.setPositiveButton("YES"){ dialog, _ -> 
    sharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply() 
    println("Shared preferences cleared")
    println("Logged out")
    dialog.dismiss()
    val intent = Intent(activity as Context, LoginActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent) 
} 
.setNegativeButton("NO"){dialog,_ ->
    val homeFragment = HomeFragment()  
    val beginTransaction = activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    beginTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, homeFragment)
    dialog.dismiss()
    beginTransaction.commit()
    activity!!.navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.home_screen) 
    println("Home title set")     
    activity!!.actionBar!!.title = "Home"
 }
.show()
```

Comment: There's no such method, apparently

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that as parameters for the clicklisteners you get a `DialogInterface` object. That object has a `dismiss()` method. You need to call that one to dismiss the dialog.

```
 val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context)
    dialog.setTitle("Confirmation")
    dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?")
    dialog.setPositiveButton("YES"){ text, listener ->
        sharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply()
        println("Shared preferences cleared")
        println("Logged out")
        val intent =  Intent(activity as Context, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    dialog.setNegativeButton("NO"){dlgInterface: DialogInterface,listener ->
        

        val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        val beginTransaction = activity?.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        beginTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, homeFragment)
        beginTransaction.commit()
        activity?.navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.home_screen)
        println("Home title set")
        activity?.actionBar?.title = "Home"

        dlgInterface.dismiss()
        
    }
    dialog.create()
    dialog.show()
```

Also please stop using force unwraping `!!`. Kotlin has this magic of safe unwraping `?` and it saves lives. Use it ;)